# How to import Int in array into strings?

Tags: arrays, string, image, integer

I tried of written too much of number from xcassest to ordered like this to make UITableView Cells with Image for a comic app that I make.

```
var image = ["18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"]
```

so i am try to make more faster to make image import the code to show the app so easier! like this.

```
var comic_IMG = [18...27]

var inttostring = String[comic_IMG]

comicsCells.IMG.image = UIImage(named: "\(inttostring[indexPath.row])")
```

however, this show an error cuz inttostring has refuse read the comic_IMG. any idea?

thanks!

Comment: Please add a language tag.  I suspect inttostring is not an index-able structure but can't be sure.

Comment: yeah actaully second has failed read int arrays so do you know how to import Int array into strinng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
var inttostring: [String] = []
for x in 18...27 {inttostring.append("\(x)")}
comicsCells.IMG.image = UIImage(named: "\(inttostring[indexPath.row])")
```